# Calling Action when state property changes

Tags: vue.js, pinia

What is the best way for me to trigger an action anytime a specific property has been changed within the state?
In this example the toggle property can be mutated from multiple places within the application. Any time toggle is mutated, i want to follow it up with executing the action toggleChanged. How would this be done? Ideally somehow within the state so the triggering is more easily manageable.

```
/**
 * General app properties
 */
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { collapse } from "myutils";

export const useAppStore = defineStore("app", {
  state: () => ({
    toggle: false,
  }),

  actions: {
    // anytime the toggle property has changed id like to trigger this event
    async toggleChanged(props) {
      console.log('Changed:', this.toggle)
      collapse(this.toggle)
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Subscribing to an action? https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html#subscribing-to-actions

Comment: Or subscribing to the state: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#subscribing-to-the-state

Comment: How would I do either of those things? Meaning which file do I place the subscription? Can I do it within the store file itself?

Comment: Either use it in a component or directly in the store yeah: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/794#discussioncomment-1643242

Comment: @kissu Please post your answer. I think it will valuable for future folks

Answer (score 0):

Although I am late, I think this might help some people.
You can use watchers to listen to the changes.

```
watch: {
  "$store.state.toggle": "toggleChanged",
},
```

toggleChanged() should be declared in the component methods and is called everytime the toggle state changes.